# Replace Wordpress menu by ID (using functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to replace a certain menu on a certain page but I cannot get it to work.

Here's what I have in my functions.php:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'show_correct_main_menu');
function show_correct_main_menu($args) {
    if ( is_page(9424) ) {
        if ( $args['menu'] = '2' ) {
            $args['menu'] = '40';
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work. What this does is it replaces ALL menus on the current page - the main menu, the menus in footer, etc. I'd like to replace just the menu that has the ID `2`.

**Is there any way to specify which menu (by ID) to replace?**

What I'd ultimately like to do is replace multiple menus on this page, something like this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'show_correct_main_menu');
function show_correct_main_menu($args) {
    if ( is_page(9424) ) {
        if ( $args['menu'] = '2' ) {
            $args['menu'] = '40';
        } elseif ( $args['menu'] = '5' ) {
            $args['menu'] = '31';
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

If I target the main menu using `$args['theme_location']` it seems to work, but I'd specifically like use menu IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed equal assign " == "

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'show_correct_main_menu');
function show_correct_main_menu($args) {
    if ( is_page(9424) ) {
        if ( $args['menu'] == '2' ) {
            $args['menu'] = '40';
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```